# Generic Multiway Merge

Tags: c++, c++11, mergesort

Recently I had a problem (not in C++) that required merging a number of sorted lists of values. This is effectively the generalised case of merging together two sorted lists. However, instead of merging them into one single list, the requirement was instead to effectively put them into "buckets" of like values. As an example, given:

> {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}

They should go into "buckets" of like values:

> {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4}, {5}

I've rewritten it in C++ for fun:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>

// Given an pair of Iterators to an outer container that has a nested
// container, such as std::vector<std::deque<T>>, where the values in each
// std::deque<T> are sorted in ascending order, will return a vector of
// Iterators where the first element is an (equal) minimum over all the containers.
// For example, given:
// std::vector<std::deque<int>> = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 5} };
// This would return iterators to the 1st and 3rd elements, as both have
// the equal minimum (here, 1) in the first position.
template <typename Iterator>
std::vector<Iterator> minimums(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    std::vector<Iterator> mins;

    if(begin == end) { return mins; }
    while(begin != end && begin->begin() == begin->end()) { ++begin; }
    if(begin == end) { return mins; } 

    mins.push_back(begin);
    ++begin;

    for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        const auto& current_min = *std::begin(*mins[0]);
        if(*(it->begin()) < current_min) {
            mins.clear();
            mins.push_back(it);
        } 
        else if(*(it->begin()) == current_min) {
            mins.push_back(it);
        }
    }

    return mins;
}

template <typename T>
void erase_front(std::list<T>& l) { l.pop_front(); }

template <typename T>
void erase_front(std::deque<T>& d) { d.pop_front(); }

// Performs a destructive multiway merge.
// The begin and end Iterators should reference a container with nested
// containers, where each nested container is sorted in ascending order.
// Further, the nested containers must support erasure from the front,
// so a std::deque is suggested here for optimal speed.
// To use a container that is not std::list or std::deque, a specialization
// for erase_front must be written for the container. This should simply
// remove the first element of the given container.
// Erasing the first element should NOT invalidate any other iterators,
// hence this should not be used where a std::vector<T> is the nested
// container.
template <typename Iterator>
auto multiway_merge(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> 
    std::vector<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>::type>
{
    using inner_container = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*begin)>::type;
    using container_type  = std::vector<inner_container>;

    container_type store;
    std::vector<Iterator> current_minimums = minimums(begin, end);

    for(; current_minimums.size() > 0; current_minimums = minimums(begin, end)) {
        auto& minimum = *(std::begin(*current_minimums[0]));
        inner_container ic;
        for(auto& mins : current_minimums) {
            while(std::begin(*mins) != std::end(*mins) && 
                  *std::begin(*mins) == minimum) {
                ic.emplace_back(std::move(*std::begin(*mins)));
                erase_front(*mins); 
            }
        }
        store.emplace_back(std::move(ic));
    }

    return store;
}
```

This is destructive to the original container, elements are moved out as they are encountered. The other way to do this (which works for non-sorted containers, and is not destructive) is to put everything into a map of some kind:

```
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename T>
struct remove_const_reference
{
    using type = typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
};

template <typename Container>
auto put_into_map(const Container& v) -> 
   std::unordered_map<typename remove_const_reference<decltype(v.front().front())>::type,
          std::vector<typename remove_const_reference<decltype(v.front().front())>::type>>
{
    using T = typename remove_const_reference<decltype(v.front().front())>::type;
    std::unordered_map<T, std::vector<T>> m;
    for(const auto& d : v) {
        for(const auto& i : d) {
            m[i].push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

This has the upside of not "destroying" the original container; however, it uses twice the memory, and since we have ordered data, in my tests it's somewhere between 1.5 to 3 times slower.

To satisfy this, the contained type must have an `operator<` and an `operator==`. Some tests:

```
template <typename Container>
void print(const Container& c)
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for(const auto& v : c) {
        std::cout << v << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

struct test_struct
{
    std::string s;
    int i;
    double j;
};

bool operator<(const test_struct& a, const test_struct& b)
{
    return a.s < b.s;
}

bool operator==(const test_struct& a, const test_struct& b)
{
    return a.s == b.s;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test_struct& ts)
{
    return os << "(" << ts.s << ", " << ts.i << ", " << ts.j << ")";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::list<int>> v = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                                     {2, 3, 4},
                                     {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}};

    auto sorted = multiway_merge(v.begin(), v.end());
    for(const auto& container : sorted) {
        print(container);
    } 


    std::vector<std::deque<test_struct>> v2 =
        {{ {"a", 1, 1.0}, {"b", 2, 2.5}, {"c", 1, 5.0} },
         { {"b", 7, 0.5}, {"c", 4, 4.5}, {"d", 1, 5.0} } };

    auto sorted2 = multiway_merge(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    for(const auto& container : sorted2) {
        print(container);
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. I consider it a bit ugly because the `Iterator` template parameters are dealing with nested containers, which makes the code harder to read, so anything that addresses that would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

My immediate reaction would be to accept a collection of ranges of some sort (e.g., Boost Range, or even just a pair of iterators).

Since the range (or iterator) types would be template parameters, the user can pass normal iterators or move iterators as s/he sees fit, so one piece of code suffices for both copying (non-destructive) and moving (destructive) merges.

I'd expect this to give sort of a half-way point between the two current pieces of code. It would probably be about the speed of the current destructive version, but potentially use more memory--it can move objects from the original container, but doesn't delete the source items from the original container as their moved to the output, so it will consume more memory than your existing destructive merge.

Memory usage will depend on whether you're dealing with objects that store most data in the object itself, or mostly store a pointer in the object and put most of the real data on the heap. In the latter case, moving out of the object will typically just move the pointer to the data into the new object, and leave only the minimal bookkeeping information in the old object, so it won't consume a lot more than the code above that deletes each item from the source container as it's moved to the destination collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `k` sorted lists containing `n` elements in total, your first approach is `O(nk)` time, while the second appears to be `O(n log n)` time. Worse, the "collect-then-throw-away" logic of your function `minimums` makes the process even slower.

The same task can be done in `O(n log k)` time by using a [binary min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_heap). The heap keeps track of which list to take the next element from. In practice, you need a very simple algorithm using `std::priority_queue`. Check [algorithm for N-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055937/2644390) for instance. Putting in buckets requires only a slight modification.

Whether you copy or move data is irrelevant, and can be controlled by move iterators as [Jerry Coffin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46432/39083) suggests.